# Do python libraries make use of Linux device drivers?

Tags: python, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c, beagleboneblack

I was wondering if some python libraries make use of device drivers? specifically:

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_BNO055

I ask this because the BNO055 is an i2c device and so i thought that it would make use of the i2c device drivers on my beagelbone black. It seems that it is not because when i list my currently loaded kernel modules i cant seem to fine any i2c device drivers:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
chr_drv_ex1            16384  0
rfcomm                 77824  4
bnep                   28672  2
hci_uart               57344  1
bluetooth             557056  28 hci_uart,bnep,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           28672  2 bluetooth
xt_state               16384  0
xt_conntrack           16384  1
nft_counter            16384  3
nft_chain_nat_ipv4     16384  4
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  1
nft_compat             20480  2
aes_arm_bs             20480  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aes_arm_bs
cryptd                 24576  1 crypto_simd
wl18xx                110592  0
wlcore                253952  1 wl18xx
mac80211              729088  2 wl18xx,wlcore
cfg80211              675840  3 wl18xx,wlcore,mac80211
pm33xx                 16384  0
wkup_m3_ipc            16384  1 pm33xx
wkup_m3_rproc          16384  1
wlcore_sdio            16384  0
usb_f_acm              16384  2
u_serial               20480  3 usb_f_acm
usb_f_ncm              28672  2
usb_f_mass_storage     53248  2
usb_f_rndis            32768  4
u_ether                20480  2 usb_f_ncm,usb_f_rndis
libcomposite           65536  18 usb_f_acm,usb_f_ncm,usb_f_mass_storage,usb_f_rndis
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0
uio                    20480  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
pruss_soc_bus          16384  0
pru_rproc              28672  0
pruss                  16384  1 pru_rproc
irq_pruss_intc         20480  1 pru_rproc
remoteproc             57344  3 pru_rproc,wkup_m3_rproc,wkup_m3_ipc
virtio                 16384  1 remoteproc
virtio_ring            28672  1 remoteproc
spidev                 20480  0
```

So now I'm wondering why my BNO055 i2c device is able to work without use of the drivers. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: A kernel module usually create nodes in `/dev/` to allow communication with the userspace. For I²C you should find nodes named like `/dev/i2c*`.

Comment: @KlausD So im i correct to assume that the python libraries incorporate some c language to communicate with the kernel from the user space?

Comment: A typical way of interfacing a kernel module is to load a shared object (`.so`) for it and use its calls directly or via a wrapper that makes it more "pythonic".

Comment: @KlausD. Do you know of a way to see which driver module is being used by a python program?

Comment: You should consider the case that the feature is compiled into the kernel directly and does need to be loaded as a module.

Comment: @KlausD, i2c device node is a bad example, because it is not proper way to go. I think it was historical due to absence of in-kernel drivers. SPI, for example, gives a big warning for such device nodes to be in use.